# View multiple mxd files in same tab of ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, layouts, mxd

I have downloaded a bunch of map sheets which all fit together into one big map. I want to merge them all such that I can export any subsection of the combined map. They are provided as .mxd files and when I open them in ArcGIS Pro using 'Import map' each one opens in a separate tab. They are all georeferenced so it should be straightforward to merge them, but I can't find the option to do this anywhere.

What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you need to merge actual datasets or just combine the maps?

Comment: @KHibma Just combine the maps so that I can export a custom selection of the combined map.